# Xamarin - Camera2Video sample stretched image

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-camera2

I am using Microsoft's sample for camera preview:
[Xamarin.Android - Camera2Video](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/monodroid-samples/android50-camera2videosample/)

On some devices the preview is OK, 
but on others (Samsung Galaxy A7) the image is stretched when device is rotated.
On other devices the image is always stretched (Honeywell CT50).

I have looked into function AutoFitTextureView.OnMeasure and it looks OK.

Example:
Square item:

[image: Square item]

Stretched image in mobile

[image: Stretched image in mobile]

Does anyone know how to fix the sample?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please add pictures or a gif to describe better what you are talking about?